# Julia - using CartesianIndices with an array

Tags: indexing, julia

I am trying to access specific elements of an NxN matrix 'msk', with indices stored in a Mx2 array 'idx'. I tried the following:

```
N = 10
msk = zeros(N,N)
idx = [1 5;6 2;3 7;8 4]
#CIs = CartesianIndices(( 2:3, 5:6 )) # this works, but not what I want
CIs = CartesianIndices((idx[:,1],idx[:,2]))
msk[CIs] .= 1
```

I get the following: ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching CartesianIndices(::Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}})

Comment: If you have any control over how the indices are stored this can be coded very cleanly. For example, if `ind = [(1,5), (6,2), (3,7), (8,4)]`, then your cartesian indices are just `CartesianIndex.(ind)`. If you are a stuck with a matrix of indices, you have to use the more convoluted solution with `eachcol`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? (I am using your definitions)

```
julia> msk[CartesianIndex.(eachcol(idx)...)] .= 1;

julia> msk
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Note that I use a vector of `CartesianIndex`:

```
julia> CartesianIndex.(eachcol(idx)...)
4-element Array{CartesianIndex{2},1}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 5)
 CartesianIndex(6, 2)
 CartesianIndex(3, 7)
 CartesianIndex(8, 4)
```

as `CartesianIndices` is:

> Define a region `R` spanning a multidimensional rectangular range of integer indices.

so the region defined by it must be rectangular.

Another way to get the required indices would be e.g.:

```
julia> CartesianIndex.(Tuple.(eachrow(idx)))
4-element Array{CartesianIndex{2},1}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 5)
 CartesianIndex(6, 2)
 CartesianIndex(3, 7)
 CartesianIndex(8, 4)
```

or (this time we use linear indexing into `msk` as it is just a `Matrix`)

```
julia> [x + (y-1)*size(msk, 1) for (x, y) in eachrow(idx)]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 41
 16
 63
 38
```